# React Native Redux-Persist not calling transformer on rehydrate

Tags: typescript, react-native, redux, react-redux, expo

I am working on a React Native (`react@~16.9.0`) Expo (`expo@~37.0.3`) Android app that is supposed to store hour registration data locally, for this `redux-persist@^6.0.0` is used.

I created a `RegistrationWeek` domain object that contains all data and some helper functions:

```js
import moment, { Moment } from "moment";
import { ..., addRegistrationWeek, updateRegistrationWeek } from '../store/register';

export class RegistrationDay {
  ...

  constructor(...) {
    ...
  }
}

export default class RegistrationWeek {
  ...

  constructor(...) {
    ...
  }

  totalTime() {
    ...
  }

  dateRange() {
    ...
  }

  ...

  static init(store?) {
    if(store) { RegistrationWeek.store = store };
    const register = RegistrationWeek.store.getState().register;
    ...
  }

  static async save(week: RegistrationWeek): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve) => {
      const register = RegistrationWeek.store.getState().register;
      const existing = register.registrationData.findIndex(w => w.startDate === week.startDate);
      if (existing >= 0) {
        updateRegistrationWeek(RegistrationWeek.store, week);
      } else {
        addRegistrationWeek(RegistrationWeek.store, week);
      }
      return resolve(week);
    });
  }

  ...

}
```

The `register.ts` file that has the `registrationReducer` in it looks as follows:

```js
import RegistrationWeek from "../models/RegistrationWeek";

...

export function addRegistrationWeek(store, week: RegistrationWeek) {
  const action: {
    type: string,
    week: RegistrationWeek,
  } = {
    type: 'ADD_REGISTRATION_WEEK',
    week,
  }
  store.dispatch(action);
}

export function updateRegistrationWeek(store, week: RegistrationWeek) {
  const action: {
    type: string,
    week: RegistrationWeek,
  } = {
    type: 'UPDATE_REGISTRATION_WEEK',
    week,
  }
  store.dispatch(action);
}

...

// Initial State
const initialState : {
  registrationData: RegistrationWeek[],
  ...
} = {
  registrationData: [],
  ...
};
// Reducers (Modifies The State And Returns A New State)
const registrationReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
  switch (action.type) {
    ...
    case 'ADD_REGISTRATION_WEEK': {
      return {
        ...state,
        registrationData: [
          ...state.registrationData,
          action.week,
        ],
      };
    }
    case 'UPDATE_REGISTRATION_WEEK': {
      const updatedArray: RegistrationWeek[] = [...state.registrationData];
      const index = updatedArray.findIndex((w: RegistrationWeek) => w.startDate === action.week.startDate);
      updatedArray[index] = action.week;
      return {
        ...state,
        registrationData: updatedArray,
      };
    }
    default: {
      return state;
    }
  }
};
export default registrationReducer;
```

This `registrationReducer` is configured and included in a `rootReducer` along with a `Transformer`:

```
// Imports: Dependencies
import { combineReducers } from 'redux';
// Imports: Reducers
import registerReducer from './register';
import { persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';
import Transformer from './transformer';

const registerPersistConfig = {
  key: 'register',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  transformers: [Transformer],
  whitelist: ['registrationData', ...],
  blacklist: [],
};

// Redux: Root Reducer
const rootReducer = combineReducers({
  register: persistReducer(registerPersistConfig, registerReducer),
});
export default rootReducer;
```

The `Transformer` looks as follows:

```js
import { createTransform, TransformInbound, TransformOutbound } from 'redux-persist';

import RegistrationWeek, { RegistrationDay } from '../models/RegistrationWeek';

interface State {
  registrationData: RegistrationWeek[],
  ...
}

const Transformer = createTransform<State, State, any, any>(
  // transform state on its way to being serialized and persisted.
  (inboundState: State, key) => {
    return { ...inboundState };
  },

  // transform state being rehydrated
  (outboundState: State, key) => {
    return {
      registrationData: outboundState.registrationData.map((w: RegistrationWeek) => {
        new RegistrationWeek(..., w.days.map((d: RegistrationDay) => {
            return new RegistrationDay(...)
      }))}),
      ...outboundState,
    }
  },

  { whitelist: ['registrationData'] }
);

export default Transformer;
```

Neither of the transformation methods seems to be called since putting `console.log(...)` statements in them does not result in any output in the console.

The `store` instance is configured here:

```js
import { createStore } from 'redux';
import { persistStore, persistReducer } from 'redux-persist';
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native'
import rootReducer from './index';

const persistConfig = {
  key: 'root',
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ['register'],
  blacklist: [],
};

// Middleware: Redux Persist Persisted Reducer
const persistedReducer = persistReducer(persistConfig, rootReducer);
// Redux: Store
const store = createStore(persistedReducer);
// Middleware: Redux Persist Persister
let persistor = persistStore(store);

const getPersistor = () => persistor;
const getStore = () => store;
const getState = () => {
    return store.getState();
};export {
    getStore,
    getState,
    getPersistor
};export default {
    getStore,
    getState,
    getPersistor
}
```

Whenever persisted data gets retrieved after launching the app, it looks like:

```js
Array [
  Object {
    "days": Array [
      Object {
        ...
      },
      ...
    ],
    ...
  },
]
```

Instead of the way it looks when saving the data:

```js
Array [
  RegistrationWeek {
    "days": Array [
      RegistrationDay {
        ...
      },
      ...
    ],
    ...
  },
]
```

I am relying on the `totalTime()` and `dateRange()` methods from the `RegistrationWeek` object in my UI but after rehydration it does not work anymore because the objects aren't instantiated properly.
Doing this as part of a component render function does work, but the downside with that is that there would be an even bigger mix of templating and data manipulation. The loops would also be repeated every time the component is rendered, which seems like an uneccesarry performance impact to me.
I hoped the strong typing, the transformer and the configuration would do the trick but somehow it does not seem to be called even though state is persisted.

If anyone has any tips, things I missed, on how to deal with this, please let me know!